# Display uploaded image by using asset

Tags: twig, symfony4

I have a form that uploads an image in the directory `upload`. When I want to display the image by using `asset`, it isn't shown.

My code to diplay the image is the following:

```
<a href="{{ asset('uploads/' ~ doaDetails.dce) }}" class="mdi mdi-file-pdf" title="DCE">
    <img src="{{ asset('uploads/Annexes' ~ doaDetails.annexe1  ) }}" >
</a>
```

Comment: is the upload folder in public? public/upload?

Comment: yes, public/uploads/Annexes

Comment: i resloved the problem thanks for you

Comment: what was ist? Did you forget the slash in <img src="{{ asset('uploads/Annexes/' ~ doaDetails.annexe1  ) }}" >?

Comment: the salsh it is my probleme,